# Typescript in Visual Studio listeners

Tags: javascript, events, typescript, mouseevent

I am new to TS, so basically what I want to achieve is creating event listener on click event. I know how to do this in pure javascript, but I am not succeeding in TS. Can someone provide me with some example ? FE I want to add listener to click event and when it is triggered call other method and pass her element on which was click action performed. In JS I have it like this, but I did not find any example how to this in TS.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {    
   ClickOnElement(event.target);
});
```

Petr

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the same code in TS. As the parameter `event` has an inferred type, you don't really need to add type annotations anywhere. So it is fine just the way it is. TS code doesn't necessarily need to be different from JS code.

Comment: But is in there TS way, how to do this ? I do not want ending up with mixing JS and TS together.